# Laptop with Windows 7 forcibly shutting down when LAN is connected

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have recently started working with virtual machines on my HP Probook. A few days back, the system started acting up: a blue screen would pop up, saying my laptop is shutting down to prevent any damage etc.

I operated the laptop in safe mode and uninstalled any recent software, including VMware (for virtual m/cs)
an additional problem I have been facing for over a month is detection of wifi connections. detection is turned on in the system, yet the computer shows no networks.

After uninstalling the software from my laptop, it is working normally, except I cannot connect to the internet in any way: connecting a LAN cable causes the blue screen to pop up again and it stays put.

I consulted two friends: one says formatting the hard disk will solve the issues, whereas another cites motherboard problems. Help :|

Answer (score 0):

Could be either a hardware OR a software issue. see here

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-system/blue-screen-windows-has-been-shut-down-to-prevent/4388a5bc-f740-4120-ab42-af40188e682b

Answer (score 0):

It does not seems the motherboard problem. Try re-installing the lan driver, if it does not solve the problem, re-installing the OS will solve the problem.